# Webassembly return c++ uint8_t array and pass that to javascript Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, c++, c++17, webassembly, emscripten

What is the best practice to return bytes array from c++ to webassembly and then pass that bytearray to Javascript Uint8Array

Currently my i have a c++ method  that takes a string as a parameter

```
var theString = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const input_array = encoder.encode(theString);
var len = input_array.length;
var bytes_per_element = input_array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 

var input_ptr  = Module._malloc(len * bytes_per_element );

Module.HEAPU8.set(input_array, input_ptr / bytes_per_element); // write WASM memory calling the set method for the Uint8Array
var extendedStringPtr = Module._functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsAndReturnsAnotherString(input_ptr, len );

var extendedStringLength = 90
var output_array = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, extendedStringPtr, extendedStringLength);
var newstring = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(output_array);
console.log(newstring);
Module._free(input_ptr);
```

and the c++ part

```
  char* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsAndReturnsAnotherString(
        char* str, int length   )
 {

    string s1(str, length);
    std::cout << "original string received from JavaScript is :" <<  s1 << std::endl;

    string s2 = ", then Godzilla jumps out and party is over! :)";
    string s3 = s1 + s2;

    std::cout << "Final string " <<  s3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Final string  length " <<  s3.length() << std::endl;

    // create a character buffer to return
     char * char_array = new char [s3.length()+1];
     strcpy (char_array, s3.c_str());

    // create a char pointer and return it
     char* arrayPtr = &char_array[0];
     return arrayPtr;

 }
```

Now the problem  here is the  "extendedStringLength" i.e. i do not have it at this particular point in time. How can i pass it in the most convenient way from  c++ to javascript.

On the internet i have seen 2 ways:

1) first is to pass to the functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsAndReturnsAnotherString method a third parameter i.e. another integer that already is living in the Module.HEAPU8 and let c++ initializie it
then i will have to read that from java script

2) create a fixed length structure such as

```
struct MyControllStruct {

uint32_t* arrayBufferPtr;
uint32_t arrayBufferLength;
};
```

https://dev.to/azure/passing-structured-data-from-c-to-javascript-in-web-assembly-1i0p
And since i know that this structure is exactly 8 bytes long i.e. 4+4 i will have to read this every time like this in JavaScript

```
var MyControllStruct =  new Int32Array(Module.HEAP32.buffer, output_ptr, 8);
```

the first integer address is the pointer to the newly created byte array and the second one is the length of that array. I am not particularly found of any of the 2 above since it seems quite a lot of work for something that should easier to do.

Is there a better way to do that?

The way the wasm is compiled from CMAKE

```
set_target_properties(wasmExec PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -s WASM=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=512MB  -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1  -s VERBOSE=1  --pre-js /src/wasm/preModule.js -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='['cwrap', 'getValue', 'setValue']'   " )
```

Addition 28 January 2020

In order to read the final string back from the Javascript I use this

```
var output_array = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, extendedStringPtr, 90);
var newstring = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(output_array);
console.log(newstring);
```

again here the problem is the Length   90 since i need to know it before i start reading the string back

Comment: is `functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsWithVariableLengthAndReturnsAnotherString` a C++ function? If then cloud you change it to `Module._ functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsWithVariableLengthAndReturnsAnotherString` to make it clear?

Comment: Also, is it a C++ class method, or just a function that can be converted to a plain C function? Maybe you can post a simple example of `functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsWithVariableLengthAndReturnsAnotherString` in C++

Comment: @BumsikKim  yes the functionThatExtendsTheOriginalStringsWithVariableLengthAndReturnsAnotherString is a c++ method that is already available under the Module_

Comment: Then can you post an simple example of that method in C++ and, more importantly, how you currently export & call the method using emcc?

Comment: ok give me a minute to rewrite to a simple function and i will post it

Comment: it's somethig like that above ,, except there is indeed random length and not "00000" but the point is the resulting buffer is different size i.e. not the original "stringSize"

Comment: no i can return the pointer to the result array but i also need to return the new length of the result array and that is the question how to do it  with the common best practice

Comment: @BumsikKim  i have placed the linked flags i guess that is what you were looking for right ?

Comment: Yeah, that will be enough to write an answer, except your original question was about `Uint8Array` but now the cpp code is `int*`...is it okay to answer in `char*` (or `uint8_t*`) version?

Comment: i guess char* should be  fine as long as it is a pointer , however i did  not manage to pass char* , although i want to pass it . I my case i am more interested about uint8_t* array but i guess the same will be valid for uint32_t* arrays as well.

Comment: @BumsikKim ok i change the function to  something more simple and now the function retruns char* . hope that it is clear now. Do you have any hint for me now?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is the Length 90 since i need to know it before i start reading the string back

If it's a null-terminated string you can do this:

```js
var max_string_len = 999;
var output_array = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, extendedStringPtr, max_string_len);
output_array = output_array.slice(0, output_array.indexOf(0));
var newstring = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(output_array);
console.log(newstring);
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the correct answer. What about if that is not null-terminated string. Currenly i am using global variables in c++ that  that i can set and then query from JavaScript. The method that you suggested is reading additional bytes that we do not need at all i.e. we need 90 and you are reading 999

Comment: I am solved my problem currenly by using global variables in the C++ code that i can query by a function from java script thus i can get the length after i execute the method. But that means that i must always call 2 methods instead of one.

Comment: Whether you use `90`, `999` or `66560` bytes, it's all the same, because creating a `Uint8Array` isn't reading anything.  It's just defining how you want to read `Module.HEAPU8.buffer`, and you always stop reading when you hit a `null` byte.  A minimum of `66560` bytes of memory are always reserved for WebAssembly anyways.